# How to get to the previous screen on cancelling taking a picture?

Tags: android, android-camera

I am using an intent to call camera and onresult to get the captured image, but if the image is not taken (on pressing cancel), i want to get back to the screen where i called the camera from

i am using this right now....but is there a better way to do this:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (!(data == null || resultCode == 0)) {

            if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST) {

                photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
            }
        } else {

            Intent intent = new Intent(ImageUploaderActivity.this,
                    ImageUploaderActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    }
```

Comment: but @Archie when image is not  taken (on pressing cancel), and user press back button then system will resume previous ImageUploaderActivity Activity Automatically  so put your All code in onResume() of Activity

Comment: The normal behavior should get you back to the Activity you called the camera from. What happens when you cancel?

Comment: in else part do nothing. It will definitely be come on the screen from where it is called.

Comment: if i am not using if-else my application crashes when i press cancel button on the camera screen. which is because i am expecting a result (an image), but capturing image is cancelled, hence it gives me a null pointer exception and crashes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am doing something similar in my app and here is my code:

```
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (data != null) {
            //When all was ok
        }
    } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
        //When it was canceled, when I press a back button while in camera app.
    } else {
        //Some other result
    }
```

Comment: yeah, i wanted something like this....i didnt knew about RESULT_CANCELED. But in RESULT_CANCELLED what will be the code?....i want to show the previous screen which is there before calling the camera....the way i use intent in the question works fine but...is there something like goBack etc.., because that intent takes me to the same activity Intent intent = new Intent(ImageUploaderActivity.this, ImageUploaderActivity.class); which doesnt look good

Comment: I don't know what you mean because I do end up in the same activity from where I called the camera. What I do is the following, after I call camera through intent, if photo is taken and saved and in my onActivityResult I get RESULT_OK then I open a new intent where I edit and display this image. If I get RESULT_CANCELED then I tell the user the photo was not taken and he is left in the original activity.

Comment: just paste what code you have in else if(resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED)

Comment: I have only a Toast message saying "Canceled", nothing else. I don't need anything else since I just want to show that this was canceled and user resumes where he started.